# No PDF preview in KBibTex

Tags: gnome, kde, pdf

I'm using KBibTex (the KDE4 version) to manage my references for some thesis work. It is not in the repos for Ubuntu 11.10, but I installed it without problems using the v. 0.4-beta1 deb from Debian's repos here: http://packages.debian.org/sid/kbibtex.

The only thing that seems not to work is the PDF-preview, which states "Cannot create preview for [file]. No part available."

I suppose it relies on some KDE PDF-viewer, but what do I install to make it work?

I should mention that I'm running the regular Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome and Unity, not KDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think ...**

I think that the KBibTex is using the Okular's Kparts /1/, /2/.

Searching kbibtex+kpart+okular /3/:

> "Last but not least, software developers need to know that KDE
>   provides an excellent platform to build upon. For example, the
>   integration of Okular's PDF viewer in KBibTeX with just a few lines of
>   code was a big plus for me."

Here with the Kubuntu 11.10 / KDE 4.7.2 the Okular packages installed:

- okular -  document viewer
- libokularcore - libraries used by the Okular document viewer
- okular-extra-backends -  additional document formats: TIFF, DjVU, EPub

Maybe the libokularcore is enough ?

**Links**

1. http://okular.kde.org/
2. http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Using_KParts
3. http://dot.kde.org/2010/10/19/thomas-fischer-kbibtex-kde-reference-manager