# I can't install kbibtex (KD4)

Tags: kde, make

I have ubuntu 11.10 and am trying to install the latest version of kbibtex but I can't do it. Anyone know how to do?
I downloaded the tar.bz2 file from KD4 page (http://home.gna.org/kbibtex/download.html), followed the instructions but I get the following error:

> ~/kbibtex-0.4-beta1/build$ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=home

```
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=BUILD_TYPE && make
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE
  QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE QT_INCLUDE_DIR QT_LIBRARY_DIR
  QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:252 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1162 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Someone can give me an idea of ​​what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

Install the necessary QT4 libs before trying to compile a program that needs them:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev qt4-dev-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

**Compiling software**

The Ubuntu has documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware

The cmake:

- http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake
- http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/documentation.html

**Build Depends**

The easy way to get the right packages is look what the official packagers are using. Browsing to the http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages or http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and downloading the kbibtex dsc file.

The latest, at the moment, is the kbibtex_0.4~beta1-1.dsc and it is telling:

> Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7.0.50~), cmake (>= 2.6~), kdelibs5-dev,
>   libpoppler-qt4-dev, libxslt1-dev, libqtwebkit-dev

The debhelper package is needed only if you are building the deb packages. So, packages needed:

- build-essential
- cmake
- kdelibs5-dev
- libpoppler-qt4-dev
- libxslt1-dev
- libqtwebkit-dev

**Binaries and more**

http://packages.ubuntu.com/

> This site provides you with information about all the packages
>   available in the Ubuntu Package archive.

You could look the if there are new binaries available for the Ubuntu. The Ubuntu Precise Pangolin ( http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=412 ) is under development an it is getting the new versions.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas

> Personal Package Archives (PPA) allow you to upload Ubuntu source
>   packages to be built and published as an apt repository by Launchpad.

Maybe someone has packed the new version of kbibtex . But note that:

> The contents of Personal Package Archives are not checked or
>   monitored. You install software from them at your own risk.

http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages

> All packages that are included in the official Debian distribution

You could download and install the Debian binaries but be careful. They are Debian not Ubuntu packages. Earlier: [No PDF preview in KBibTex](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82177/no-pdf-preview-in-kbibtex).

**Requesting new/backported packages**

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports